# Image File Not Found in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, input, paths

I am trying to use the `includegraphics` command alongside a custom command to include an image in my PDF file, however I'm running into an issue where LaTeX can't seem to find a file that clearly exists on my system.

Here's the line that has the issue:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{\matlabgraph{rplot}}
```

where these are defined in the class file:

```
\newcommand{\matlabvalue}[1]{\input{\datadir{value/#1.dat}}}
\newcommand{\matlabgraph}[1]{\datadir{graph/#1.png}}
```

and `\datadir` is defined in the command line:

```
pdflatex "\newcommand\datadir[1]{\detokenize{C:/Users/<user>/AppData/...}/#1}\input{D:/Users/<user>/path/to/tex}"
```

The odd thing is that the `\matlabvalue` command works perfectly, but the `\matlabgraph` command does not.  It gives me the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/.../graph/rplot.png` not found.
```

When I navigate to the directory listed in the error, I see the `rplot.png` file and can open it without any issues.  The only issue I can think of that could cause this is that in the path to the file (in `<user>`) there's a tilde (`~`).  However, I would expect that the `\detokenize` in the command line would've taken care of that...as it works with the `\matlabvalue` command.

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on here?  Do I have to cleanup the path before passing it into `\includegraphics`?

UPDATE: I have discovered that the problems lies with the `\matlabgraph` command.

I put these two lines into my tex file:

```
\includegraphics{\datadir{graph/rplot.png}}
\includegraphics{\matlabgraph{rplot}}
```

The first line works, but the second line causes an error.  Considering that `\matlabgraph{rplot}` is effectively a shorthand for `\datadir{graph/rplot.png}` why would `\includegraphics` error out with `\matlabgraph`?

Comment: Please post code we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem (a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Answer (score 2):

This code will not work:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand\myimage[1]{#1}
  \newcommand\mymyimage[1]{\myimage{#1}}
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{\myimage{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.png}}
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{\mymyimage{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b.png}}
\end{document}
```

This is because the commands try to include the file `{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b.png}` i.e. it is treated as a single thing.

Making the following change allows the code to work:

```
  \newcommand\mymyimage[1]{\myimage#1}
```

This is because the additional set of curly brackets, which causes the grouping effect is removed.

At least, I think so. At any rate, it does work.